# jQuery fadeIn paragraph

Tags: jquery, fadein, fadeout, paragraph

I want to let my text fade in when click on a menu link. So when I click on "home" I want to fadeIn that text, but it doens't work. Whats wrong with my code?

```
jQuery(function ($) {
$('a#homeactiv').click(function(){
  $(this).find('p#paragraph').fadeIn(slow);
});
{
});
```

Here is a part of my html,css,jquery: http://jsfiddle.net/35qwb/2/

Comment: You should be more specific. Where is p#paragraph? is it inside the menu or is it the page content? is it loaded before you click a#homeactiv or it is to be loaded and fadedIn after?

Comment: I suggest you show your related HTML as well.  The problem might not be in your javascript.

Comment: @Peanut, the problem most certainly **is** the JavaScript.

Comment: @Peanut i put a link so you can see my html, css, and jquery

Answer (score 3):

Many things, including but not limited to:

- Prefacing an ID selector with an element.  Always just do: `$('#foo')` NOT `$('a#foo')`.
- A typo (an extra `{`).
- An extra dollar sign for some reason.
- Not putting quotes around `'slow'`.

This should work:

```
jQuery(function() {
    $('#homeactiv').click(function(){
        $('#paragraph').fadeIn('slow'); 
    });
});
```

Basically you need to learn jQuery before asking people to fix your code.  There [lots of beginner tutorials](http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/tutorials/jquery-beginner-tutorials/) that you should read first.

Comment: It still doens't work, i put a html link in my question, can you check if somethings wrong in there? Thnx

Comment: @MaartenPost It works fine, you just have an HREF attribute on your links (to .html pages) which the browser will follow.  I added a line to stop it from doing that.  http://jsfiddle.net/35qwb/3/

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of the find, that's not how jQuery is supposed to run.  Further, don't pass slow to the function unless you have a variable named slow, it's supposed to be a string or a number.

```
$("#paragraph").fadeIn("slow");
```

If you just do `$("#paragraph").fadeIn(slow)` jQuery will look for a variable called `slow` and pass it into the  fadeIn method.  As there is no variable called `slow` it will pass 0, meaning the method should run in 0 milliseconds, and show instantly.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you have a syntax error in your code, try

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('a#homeactiv').click(function() {
        $('#paragraph').fadeIn('slow');
    });
});
```

Additionally, `$(this).find('p#paragraph')` would find only `p#paragraph` that is a descendant of `a#homeactiv`. Switch to a simple query — `$('#paragraph')`

Answer (score 0):

try this:

id is unic, dont neet to set any more them she.

```
$('#homeactiv').click(function(){ 
    $("#paragraph").fadeIn('slow'); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have quite a few mistakes in your code (as pointed out by the other answers). The code below illustrates the proper way to accomplish your goal.

**HTML**

```
<p id="paragraph">
    This is example text <br />
    This is example text <br />
    This is example text <br />
    This is example text <br />
</p>

<button id="homeactiv">Click Me</button>
```

JavaScript

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $('#homeactiv').click(function() {
        $('#paragraph').fadeIn("slow");
    });
});
```

Here's [a working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/35qwb/1/).